# JavaScript iterations and conditional statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Following snippet shows a block of code which is executed at each request. At each request, `now` variable changes with the current time.

```
var now = parseInt(parseInt(Math.round(new Date())).toString().slice(0, -4))
// Real ad_time is 1421108173. But we're splicing the last second. 
var ad_time = 142110817;
var ad_duration = 30;

if (now == ad_time_10) {
   // do some stuff
} else if (now == ad_time_10+1) {
   // do some other stuff
} else if (now == ad_time_10+2) {
   // do some another stuff
} else if (now == ad_time_10+3) {
   // do some very different stuff
} else if (now == ad_time_10+4) {
   // do some very really different stuff
}
.
.
.
.
```

`ad_time_10` and `ad_duration` are previously set variables. `ad_time_10` is 10th second of a given time. The reason is I need to do some stuff at 10th seconds of the current time. `ad_duration` variable determines how many `if` statements will exist. For example, if `ad_duration` is 30 seconds, I need to check 5 requests after it. If `ad_duration` is 120 seconds, I will need to check 14 requests. If `ad_duration` is 240 I will need to check 26 requests and so on...

So how can I do this job without manually checking for conditions?

Thanks

Comment: Btw, you're cutting too much. The `now` is not a unix timestamp.

Comment: Yes, as I've tried to explain, I'm using current time in 10 seconds of pieces. Please ignore it, is my question understandable? :\

Comment: A side note: `Math.ceil(new Date() / 10000)` this would do the same and is twice shorter.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I'll keep it :) Any opinions on my primary question?

Comment: How 30 -> 5, 120 -> 14, 240 -> 26 values are calculated?

Comment: At each 10 second a request is received and I need to make some calculations at the each step until 3rd request after the ad_time_10 value. So I basically add 2 requests. 30 seconds means 3 requests and I'm adding 2 requests to it and I get 5.

Comment: If for each condition you must run different code, I don't think you can simplify it much.  But you can try a `switch` of `ad_time_10 - now` with cases `0`, `1`, ...